# bit change from 32bit JPG to 14bit grayscale My math is wrong

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, mathematical-optimization

I have 14bit image, then I do some processing as a JPG, then I convert it back as a 14bit.
But my math is all wrong in the end.

I try to use the original Min/Max values.

```
ushort[,] outputImage = new ushort[sourceBitmap.Height, sourceBitmap.Width];
//Max = White Min = White ... relatively
int distance = io_current.MaximumValue - io_current.MinimumValue;
```

As a distance... value.  But I don't know if this is correct.  The Jpg is PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb
It is still a grayscale image, so I just take the BlueColor, because they are all the same values:

While traversing the JPG in a for-loop Rows and Cols: Each value
My code is actually creating a new JPG this way:

```
resultBuffer[byteOffset] = (byte)(blueTotal);
resultBuffer[byteOffset + 1] = (byte)(greenTotal);
resultBuffer[byteOffset + 2] = (byte)(redTotal);
resultBuffer[byteOffset + 3] = 255;
```

As already stated, blue, green, and Red, will be all the same values.

So here is where my math gets wonky:

```
long total = (long)(255 - blueTotal); //invert the value;
total = ((total * distance) / 255); //Convert to 14bit within the 
                                   //confines of the  original Min and Max
if (total < io_current.MinimumValue) total = io_current.MinimumValue;
else if (total > io_current.MaximumValue) total = io_current.MaximumValue;

outputImage[offsetY, offsetX] = (ushort)total;
```

Note: I could change 'Distance' to 38416: The 14bit maximum, but both numbers yield bad results.

Comment: Man, the JPBG is never in this PixelFormat - you deal with BITMAPS. Whether or not you then store them as JPB is irrelevant, the question never processes and Jpg, it processes a BITMAP.

Comment: Where do you get 14 bit values from ? (Also Note that you can't save 16-bit grayscale in GDI..)

Comment: Yes that proves I'm in the Amateur hour, but doesn't change the question.  I edited the code-presentation problem.  You commented before I was done editing.  Thankx

Comment: High-end cameras produce that... But again that's not important.  Oh the issue is I'm producing a 'Black' image in 'outputImage'.  Why?

Comment: I didn't really mean the source but how you access/open/read it. Or do you read it in as bitmaps from jpg images? Have you observed some pixels in the debugger? And how is blueTotal etc created/calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly:

- You have an image with 14-bit greyscale pixels.
- You know the existing minimum and maximum values.
- You are converting this to 8-bit greyscale for processing.
- You wish to re-convert to 14-bit greyscale, mapped to the original min-max range.

If that's correct, then assuming you have saved your original range:

```
double dMin = yourOriginalMin, dMax = yourOriginalMax;
```

Then the range you want to map to is of size:

```
double dRange = dMax - dMin;
```

So now you have a pixel in the range 0 to 255, and you want to map it back to your 14-bit range:

```
unsigned char uSrcPixel = 111; // some arbitrary value for example

ushort uDstPixel = dMin + ((double)uSrcPixel / 255.0) * dRange;
```

Does that help?

Comment: Wow Roger this is really good.  You are spot on, what I needed.  However the Bitmap has intensities in  the 0-255 range that are inverted to the ushort pixel range.  I had thought all I had to do to invert them was  
    double total = 255 - blueTotal; But that is not working.  Then I have:  
    double d = (total / 255.0) * distance;
    ushort uDstPixel = (ushort)(io_current.MinimumValue + d);

Comment: The values are coming up inverted, and for the life of me, I'm not figuring out how to correct it.  I thought it would be a simple subtraction, but it is proving to be much more difficult.  Your calculations seem nice.  But the resultant data in uDstPixel is inverted.  How do I fix this? See above where I have a comment 'Invert the value' But that is not working.  This is: 0-255 in the bitmap mapped to the 14bit with MIN/MAX with generally 2000+ being White or 'Min'.

Comment: double total = 255 - blueTotal;
double d = (total / 255.0) * range;
ushort uDstPixel = (ushort)(d - (io_current.MinimumValue * 2));

Oh the subtraction to (MinimumValue * 2) is purely speculation... and I know is inaccurate. But it is getting my image closer to what I expect it should look like for the previously written 14bit viewer.  I can save a JPG from the bitmap and it looks pretty good.

Comment: Well just try `uDstPixel = dMax - ((double)uSrcPixel / 255.0) * dRange` and see what you get.

Comment: Nope: Values too high (Dark).. The bitmap is still better. Some calculation is off.

Comment: I've tried just adding a fudge-factor: Like subtracting 4000 from the value, but that still does not yield the same quality as the Bitmap.Save() So something is different.

Comment: As you likely suspected: It was my rendering engine for the Raw 14-bit that was throwing off the view.  Thank you your answer was correct!

Comment: Hey Roger, or anybody else? 'What if I don't know the existing 'Min and Max'?  In the processing of the bitmap before converting back to ushort array, the Min and Max is likely altered.  Is there a way to recalculate this as part of the reconversion?

Comment: @RobertKoernke just recalculate the min and max by a single pass through your pixels before converting.

Comment: this sounds good, but I don't understand.. You make it sound so easy.  I even created an entirely new (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843474/convert-bitmap-to-image-ushort-bytearray-with-new-min-and-max) item.